# Honda FIT 2011 Smart Key

Tags: honda, key, keyless-entry, security, smartkey

I am new to this forum and this is my first post. I came searching for Honda fit answers and now i am here in the forum seeking for FIT owners help or suggestions.

I bought a Honda FIT 2011 as a second owner for a reasonable price. First owner have lost the smark key and broken the second smart key as he told me.

Now i only have the Key taken from the remote. That is the one and only i have.

Here is a pic of it.

[image]

The below part is missing.

[image]

Now i have only the half part of Remote which is the key.  That is what i am using to lock/unlock the door and to start the car.

1/ I need to know badly how i can get the remote back. So that i can easily lock and unlock the doors.

2/ How to have a extra key ?

Please i would really really appreciate anyone's help or advice on this matter and tell me how much time and cost roughly it would require..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](http://blog.keylessentryremotefob.com/2014/03/2011-honda-fit-key-fob-remote.html):

> There is no onboard programming procedure for this vehicle. This vehicle requires special equipment be connected to the vehicle to program the keyless remote. Try a locksmith before the dealership, they are usually 50% the cost.

You'll have to purchase a replacement key/fob (or two) and then take it somewhere to have it programmed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you tell me how much time was taken to do this (cut and program) and any idea about the special equipment name they used ?

Comment: And will the new key be identical to the key i have or it will physically be identically but internally will have to different UID's

Comment: I don't know how much time it will take to make the spare. I'm sure to cut the key is the same as any other key. The programming is probably dependent upon the skill of the equipment operator. Every key is coded differently. There is a transponder in the key which is unique. The equipment they use will allow the car to *learn* the new key. The key's transponder is programmed into the car's on board recognition system and will then identify your key as an approved key and then will allow the vehicle to start (or open the door or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this source](http://www.fitfreak.net/forums/fit-diy-repair-maintenance/30638-programming-oem-fit-sport-key.html/) it's possible to program door lock/unlock with a $35 "blank" remote. The immobiliser part of it is unfortunately a bit more high tech (like you would hope). All you need to do is a set sequence with the ignition and remote to reprogram it. I'm not sure if the model's of the fit remote they are talking about and your 2011 are compatible though.